# "Помер" или "умер"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, диалекты

Многие словари считают *"помер"* просторечным. *Но не было ли оно основным примерно до революции?*

Некоторые употребляют исключительно слово *"помер"* (никогда не говорят *"умер"*), например мой друг-одногруппник из Братска. А из тех, кто привык к *"умер",* многие (или хотя бы некоторые) думают, что, если кто-то сказал *"помер",* значит, он немного небрежно или не очень хорошо относится к покойнику. Но, как я уже сказал, есть те, кто говорит *"помер"* совершенно с тем же отношением и смыслом, что и другие *"умер",* часто с уважением и любовью к человеку.

Итак, *как же правильно относиться к этому слову? Насколько правы или неправы представители каждого из типов, которые я описал? И действительно ли "помер" более характерно для жителей провинции?*

Answer (score 1):

По данным Национального корпуса руского языка в 1900—1917 гг. слово «помер» встречается в текстах в 3,5–4,1 раза реже, чем «умер». «Помер» преобладает в художественных текстах и часто в прямой речи, а «умер» встречается и в прямой речи, и в публицистике, и в более-менее официальных документах.

Если изобразить частотность употребления на графике по годам, то слово «помер» упоминается стабильно, а кривая слова «умер» ведёт себя чуть более волатильно.

На интервале 1990—2010 гг. картина аналогична, но нельзя не заметить слабую нисходящую тенденцию употребления слова «помер». Оно ниже, чем в 1917 году, и к 2010 году линейно идёт вниз. А вот слово «умер» остаётся в среднем в 3—5 раз более популярным, и при этом его частотность по годам всё также неравномерна.

К сожалению, Национальный корпус не позволяет определить, насколько характерно употребление слова «помер» в провинции. Однако при поиске в диалектном корпусе можно заметить, что частотность «умер» и «помер» различается уже не в 3—4 раза, а примерно раза в полтора — два. То есть «умер» всё равно преобладает, но уже не так убедительно.

Таким образом, словари совершенно правы: литературная норма — это «умер». Слово «умер» эмоционально более нейтрально, а «помер» может приобретать различную коннотацию и эмоциональную окраску в зависимости от контекста. В художественных текстах с его помощью легче передать широкий спектр эмоций: от сострадания до иронии.

См. Национальный корпус русского языка: [умер](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80) [помер](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&startyear=1981&text=lexform&req=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80&endyear=2001&mode=main&env=alpha&nodia=1&p=1).

Comment: Спасибо! ******